# How do I split text into 2 columns from a single column using flex but with the same heading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm creating a footer for my website and the main link is called Club Links. I could just display all 20 club links one under the other, but I'm trying to split it into 2 columns of 10. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofghu.png)

I tried using flex, but it d[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhPht.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7ETJ.png)idn't work. Anyone got tips?

Comment: Can you edit your post and copy/paste the code here as a code snippet please? You'll get a much faster response as people can scrutinise your code and also copy/paste it to an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Investigate CSS grid.

Answer (score 1):

you can put all your links into a container and use grid css or flex option

something like that

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 20px;
}

/* styles for option with grid */
.links {
  display: grid;
  gap: 8px 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

/* styles for option with flex */
.linksWithFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.link {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
option with grid
<footer class='footer'>
    <div class='col'>col1</div>
    <div class='col'>col2</div>
    <div class='col'>
      <h4 class='title'>title</h4>
      <div class='links'>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
        <a href='#'>test link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  
  option with flex
  <footer class='footer'>
    <div class='col'>col1</div>
    <div class='col'>col2</div>
    <div class='col'>
      <h4 class='title'>title</h4>
      <div class='linksWithFlex'>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
        <a href='#' class='link'>test link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, the thing is keeping it from working is that you are not applying styles to the col2 classes where the columns are, here's a quick way you could do to fix this:
Wrap the classes col2 inside a div as follows:

```
<div class="columnsContainer">
  <div class="col2">...</div>
  <div class="col2">...</div>
</div>
```

and apply the following styles to "columnsContainer" and "col2" classes:

```
.columnsContainer{
  display: flex;
}

.col2{
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

you can add different styles here but the core that will order the columns the way you want is this.

Let me know if this worked for you